# Подключение скриптов js, css на WP

Tags: javascript, плагин

Есть необходимость подключить несколько плагинов:

1. http://joaopereirawd.github.io/animatedModal.js/
2. http://codyhouse.co/gem/vertical-timeline/

При подключении в хэдэре/футэре более одного скрипта - всё катится к чертям. Путь к файлам указал. Я так понимаю, что они начинают между собой конфликтовать из-за многоразового подключения библиотек в одном файле(?).

Как, в каком виде и куда мне нужно залить скрипты этих двух плагинов для полноценной работы, и в дальнейшем для возможного подключения дополнительных плагинов?

**Обновление**

Консоль ошибок не даёт, просто всё перестаёт работать, слайдер который я устанавливал первым, после добавления новых ссылок/скриптов, так же просто перестаёт работать. Я нашёл, что их нужно добавлять в «functions.php» и использовать вызов функций `add_action()` и `wp_enqueue_script()`, к примеру вот так:

```
<?php
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'twentytwelve_tabs');
function twentytwelve_tabs() {
  wp_enqueue_script('twentytwelve_tabs', get_stylesheet_directory_uri(). '/scripts/my-code.js', array('jquery'));
}
?>
```

Но мой уровень не позволяет мне с этим ничего поделать.

Comment: Добавьте дополнительную информацию, хотя бы вывод консоли (Chrome - `Ctrl+Shift+J`)

Comment: Подробное досье на чертей — в студию! Мы ж не телепаты, как мы поймём, что сломалось, без логов ошибок?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.2.0/animate.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <script src="js/modernizr.js"></script>
</head>

...

<body>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/animatedModal.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
```